# Adding multiple virtual monitors to a PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, vnc

Ideal setup: physical monitors 1,2,3 virtual monitors 4,5,6
The PC runs a software that displays charts. 2 people(1 remote user, 1 onsite user) are sharing the software. The remote user will use screens 4,5,6 using Teamviewer/VNC.

How can I do this without physically connecting 6 monitors? The PC supports 6 monitors with 1920x1080 res.

Answer (score 0):

SpaceDesk does this. It creates a remote session on a new monitor. You don't need Teamviewer or VNC with this solution but you could continue to do so after using spacedesk to make the virtual monitors.

https://www.spacedesk.net/